# Remove square brackets with parameter expansions

Tags: bash

I have an environment variable like so:

```
VAR=[["val1","val2"],["val3","val4"]]
```

I do not control the data so the actual number of values and arrays may vary but it follows this array format.  There may be more or less results than is depicted in the example above. I am trying to strip the angle brackets so it looks like:

> "val1","val2","val3","val4"

Using only bash string manipulation.

I am halfway there.  If I do:

```
echo ${VAR//[/}
```

It removes all the left brackets.  But I cannot figure out what sort of syntax is needed to remove left and right bracket at same time.  It doesn't appear to be regex format and I am struggling to find any similar example in the docs.  (I am using Ubuntu 20.04)

What is the pattern to remove both of these square brackets with the bash filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a bracket expression to match both opening and closing brackets.

```
$ VAR='[["val1","val2"],["val3","val4"]]'
$ echo "${VAR//[][]/}"
"val1","val2","val3","val4"
```

Bracket expressions are documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html), and [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05).

This will handle *arbitrarily* complex depths, such as with:

```
$ VAR='[["val1","val2"],["val3","val4"]],[a,[b,[c,[d,[e,[[[[[[[[[[[f,g]]]]]]]]]]],h],i]]]'
$ echo "${VAR//[][]/}"
"val1","val2","val3","val4",a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
```